# Error: his could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements in test-library

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to use `screen` test-library to find the text existed on doc. My html is output like `<div>Hello <span>world</span></div>` but when I use `screen.getByText(/Hello word/i)` i have the error, `Unable to find an element with the text: /Hello word/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible. nay better way for me to use without creating a textMatch function?